# XP CHKDSK finds error when run in OS or safe mode, but does not find errors using /F on restart

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, chkdsk

I have an XP system that reports "CHKDSK discovered free space marked as allocated in the volume bitmap" when CHKDSK is run from the normal XP environment or from command-line safe mode.

When I schedule a CHKDSK /F and it runs on restart, it finds no errors.

The next time the system is runs CHKDSK in normal XP or safe mode, the same error is reported.

I saw an article that points to [this KB](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=315688), but I didn't find anything helpful there.

I noticed that the stats report "65536 KB occupied by the log file". Is there a limit on the log file size?

Comment: Do you see the same behaviour using the /R switch? I know it takes longer, but humour me please.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has reported that running `chkdsk` in the "read-only" mode can return false error indications.

Comment: I've read that elswewhere, but do you have a citation on that? (maybe something on the MS site) ?